# Can I use the Here Android SDK and Here Platform Data Extension to get the traffic sign data along the route?

Tags: here-api

Can I use the Here Android SDK and Here Platform Data Extension to get the traffic sign data along the route? e.g. Can I get all info shown in the attached image?

[image]

Comment: The image link is:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/wJwQC.jpg

Comment: This can be achieved, Once a route is available , you should be able to extract the LinkIds from the route and then further use PDE Traffic Sign Layer TRAFFIC_SIGN_FCn (documentation : http://pde.cit.api.here.com )

Answer (score 0):

To begin using the PDE layers, create a PlatformDataRequest object:

```
Set<String> layers = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("TRAFFIC_SIGN_FC1", "TRAFFIC_SIGN_FC2"));
Set<Long> linkIds = /*your link IDs*/
PlatformDataRequest request = PlatformDataRequest.createLinkIdsRequest(layers, linkIds);
```

Next, you need to supply a Listener object to get the results of the request.

```
  request.execute(new PlatformDataRequest.Listener<PlatformDataResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onCompleted(PlatformDataResult data, PlatformDataRequest.Error error) {
    if (error != null) {
      Log.w(TAG, "PlatformDataRequest failed with error: " + error);
    } else {
      // process received data
    }
  }
});
```

Please find documentation here: developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/platform-data-extension.html